# Python not using global variable in function even when global command is used

Tags: python, function, global

I am trying to change the value of a global variable in a function, however this is not happening even when "global" is specified before attempting to use/alter the variable.

Here is an abstraction of what I did (real code is quite long):

```
testVariable = 0

def functionExample():
     global testVariable
     # other code
     testVariable = 5
     print(testVariable) # this prints 5

functionExample()
print(testVariable) # this prints 0
```

If you run this code yourself, it will probably correctly assign 5 to "testVariable". However, in my code it does not do this. Here is the actual code if this helps (the code is meant for a strategy game):

```
keepPos = ("N/A","N/A")

def createBuilding3x3(mPos,coinCounterLocal,mouseSquareX,mouseSquareY,selectedBuilding,keepPlaced):
    global keepPos
    if keepPlaced != True:
        gridSquareEmpty = True
        for x in range (-1,2):
            for y in range (-1,2):
                if SSA[mouseSquareX+x][mouseSquareY+y] != 2:
                    gridSquareEmpty = False
                for i in buildingGroup:
                    if (mouseSquareX+x,mouseSquareY+y) == (i.getTileX(),i.getTileY()):
                        gridSquareEmpty = False
        if gridSquareEmpty == True:
            for x in range (-1,2):
                for y in range (-1,2):
                    if (x,y) != (0,0):
                        invisibleBuilding = Building(mouseSquareX+x,mouseSquareY+y,invisibleImage,0)
                        buildingGroup.add(invisibleBuilding)
            newBuilding = Building(mouseSquareX,mouseSquareY,imageList[selectedBuilding],0)
            buildingGroup.add(newBuilding)
            keepPos = (mouseSquareX,mouseSquareY)
            print(keepPos) # this returns (mouseSquareX,mouseSquareY)
            print("The amount of active buildings is",len(buildingGroup))
            return True
    if keepPlaced == True:
        return True
    return False

# the function is run during the program, after which:
print(keepPos) # this returns ("N/A","N/A")
```

Is my python cursed? Or have I just overlooked something? Thank you if you have any ideas as to what is wrong. Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: When do you *call* `createBuilding3x3`?

Comment: Yeah, your python is cursed..  or, y'know you could add a `print()` before you try change its value to check it runs. But, it's cursed.

Comment: you didnt include enough code for us to run an example that actually demonstrates the problem ... you gave a great toy example... but then said it works as expected, then you gave the "actual" code but not enough to actually call it and see it print the correct thing and then the wrong thing ....

Comment: additionally since keepPos is mutable you could just set the indices, rather than explicitly call global... ie `keepPos[0] = mouseX; keepPos[1] = mouseY`

Comment: `keepPos` is only changes if `keepPlaced` is False and `gridSquareEmpty` comes up True.  By the way, NEVER write expressions that compare a variable to `True` or `False`.  Instead, do `if not keepPlaced:` and `if gridSquareEmpty:`.  It reads better, and it's more flexible.  And you could end the function with `return keepPlaced`.

Comment: in first version you first execute `functionExample()` and later you check `print(testVariable)` but in second version you don't execute `createBuilding3x3(...)` and it can't change value in variable. You could also use more `print()` inside `def createBuilding3x3(...)` to see which part of code is executed. Maybe this function doesn't change your variable.

Comment: You might want to check out [codereview.se] where you may get general improvement suggestions.

Comment: @chepner
The function is called from another module which imports this function. The function works as intended except it doesn't change the value of keepPos.

Comment: @JoranBeasley If you wish, I could somehow send you the rest of the code, or of this module.

Comment: @JoranBeasley as for the second comment, when I try this it reports: TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @TimRoberts It prints the local value of keepPos and the "active amount of buildings" text, so I know that it has passed these previous validation checks. As for your tip to improve code efficiency, thank you, I will use this in the future.

Comment: @furas Apologies, I should have made it clearer that the function is executed before being printed outside of the function. I know that it is definitely changing the local value of the variable, because it prints ("N/A","N/A") before and after the function is executed, but (mouseSquareX,mouseSquareY) while it is being executed.

Comment: better create minimal working code with your problem so we could test it on our computers.

Comment: @furas the first example given really is the minimal code... the code is quite long and has quite a few modules and other files involved... maybe putting it on github would be the best solution?

Comment: i answered your question ... the problem is not the global ...

Comment: `keepPos` is only assigned a new value if `gridSquareEmpty` is true.  So, it must be that `gridSquareEmpty` is **not** true, and thus `keepPos` was not reassigned a new value.

Comment: @JoranBeasley If the problem isn't with the global variable, what is it with? The value of keepPos is definitely changed during the function, and the function is definitely executed, but the variable remains unchanged outside of the function.

Comment: @JohnGordon gridSquareEmpty is definitely true, because `print(keepPos)` prints the value of keepPos inside the function, which it wouldn't if gridSquareEmpty was false.

Comment: In the code sample you posted, the `createBuilding3x3()` function is **defined** but it is never **called**.  So if you are seeing output from `print(keepPos)`, that must mean the function **is** called, which then also means that the code is different from what you have posted.  We cannot answer questions about code that differs from what you have posted...

Comment: Are you sure that the output of `print(keepPos)` you are seeing is from **this** function?  Is there some **other** function that also prints keepPos, and perhaps **that** is the output you are seeing, and **this** function is never called?

Comment: Before keepPos is printed, also print some other unique message that does not appear anywhere else in the program, and then check to verify that message appears in the output, so that we know **this** function is called.

Comment: In short, there are lots of things you can do to verify that the code you **think** is running, is **actually** running.  But you haven't done those things.  Why not?

Comment: @JohnGordon Apologies, I should have made it clear that the function was called by showing code calling it, rather than saying in a comment that it was called. However, it is definitely called, because the rest of the function acts correctly, other than the keepPos variable. This is the only function that uses keepPos.

Comment: The only real answer here is to show the whole code.  You must have made some mistake or incorrect assumption along the way, and the only way to find it is to see the whole code.

Comment: @JohnGordon Here is a link to a github repository I have just made:
[link](https://github.com/derpybookshelf/Project-P2.git) It should run. You will need libraries pygame and pathfinding. I hope this helps

Comment: Looking at that repository, I only see two references to that variable.  `global keepPos` on line 77 of `P2.py` in the `createBuilding()` function (which is odd, because that function never actually **uses** the variable, so why bother having it global at all?), and `print(keepPos)` on line 118 also in `P2.py` inside a main-level loop. It is never **assigned** a value at all. This cannot be the whole code?

Comment: @JohnGordon It is assigned twice in the buildingPlacementProcedures.py, at the start it is assigned `("N/A","N/A")` and in the `createBuilding3x3` function which assigns it the value of `(mouseSquareX,mouseSquareY)`

Comment: Why so it is -- I overlooked the `buildingPlacementProcedures.py` module.  My mistake.

Comment: Are you expecting the assignment `keepPos = (mouseSquareX,mouseSquareY)` inside `buildingPlacementProcedures.createBuilding3x3()` to be visible inside the `P2.py` module?  If so, I think that is the problem.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildingPlacementProcedures.py` contains this assignment at the outermost level:

```
keepPos = ("N/A","N/A")
```

That module also assigns to that variable inside a function:

```
def createBuilding3x3(...):
    global keepPos
    ...
    if gridSquareEmpty == True:
        ...
        keepPos = (mouseSquareX,mouseSquareY)
```

The module `P2.py` contains this import:

```
from buildingPlacementProcedures import *
```

... which imports the `keepPos` variable and the `createBuilding3x3()` function, among many others.

However, this imports **only the initial value** of `keepPos`.  Any further changes to `keepPos` that occur inside the `buildingPlacementProcedures` module (such as when `createBuilding3x3()` is called from `P2.py`) **will not** be visible inside the `P2.py` module.

That is the source of your confusion.  It seems you expected `global` to apply program-wide, but it does not; it only applies module-wide.

If you want to keep track of the changing value of a global variable *inside another module*, you have to refer to it **explicitly using the namespace of that module**.

i.e., you need something like this:

```
import buildingPlacementProcedures

print(buildingPlacementProcedures.keepPos)
```

Comment: Thank you, this problem kept me stuck for days.